# What is the alternative of ng-cloak(angularjs) in Angular 7 for boolean variable not for object

Tags: angular, angular7, ngcloak

ngIf causes links on my page to show during load time, and then disappear.

The link is not supposed to show at all, and I am assuming that the ngIf statement hasn't been processed yet for the second I am able to see it.

Is there a way to prevent the link or element from showing at all?

In the below code my Boolean isEquipmentAssociated gets true in ngOninit,ngOnChanges and even I tried to make it true in constructor.

I have tried to do it with Css by doing display:none !important
And also with '?' operator.but that is useful for object only.

```
//code goes here
<html>
<span *ngIf="isEquipmentAssociated">
   <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
      // some other code
</span>
</html>
//code ends here
```

I expect my icon not to show at all from the beginning.

Comment: Can you show us where `isEquipmentAssociated` is coming from in your component?

Comment: Since here you are doing reactive coding, Please try using ngIf in the following manner.

*ngIf="isEquipmentAssociated | async"

Comment: initialize isEquipmentAssociated to false while declaring the variable